# Replacing strings in a column sequentially

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am naive to macros. I have data in column A with 500 rows of data. Note some rows are blank in between. The data are image files names like (X0011@00.jpg). I need to rename them sequentially with user input. The user input must be only 400500. The new name must be like (400500_Image-1.jpg). The _Image-1, _Image-2 and so on must be generated automatically in sequence omitting blank rows.

See below how my data is displayed in column A and how I want it in column B.

I appreciate if anyone can provide macro for this.

```
  Col A              Col B

X0011@00.jpg    400500_Image-1.jpg
X0021@00.jpg    400500_Image-2.jpg
X0041@00.jpg    400500_Image-3.jpg

X0071@00.jpg    400500_Image-4.jpg
X0051@00.jpg    400500_Image-5.jpg


X0031@00.jpg    400500_Image-6.jpg
X0061@00.jpg    400500_Image-7.jpg
X0091@00.jpg    400500_Image-8.jpg
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub naming()
RowsToProcess = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j = 1

userInput = InputBox("Give me text")

For i = 1 To RowsToProcess
   If Not Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then

    Cells(i, 2).Value = userInput & "_Image-" & j & ".jpg"
    j = j + 1
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

This macro creates column B as desired

Comment: Wonderful, it works. But I appreciate if the user input is pop-up, not predefined in column C. Thanks

Comment: added the userInput from an InputBox